# SelectedIndexChanged event isn't fired after onchange

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to validate a Dropdown list on client side for its selected index/value.
I want a function that alerts when the selected index is 0 or it should execute the `SelectedIndexChandged` method in the code behind..

I have written the following code..

```
function validateDropDown() {
        var indexService = document.getElementById('<%= ddlService.ClientID>').selectedIndex;
        var indexTower = document.getElementById('<%= ddlManager.ClientID>').selectedIndex;
        if (indexTower == 0) {
            document.getElementById('<%= ddlService.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('<%= ddlDate.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
            alert("Please select a Tower");
            return false;
        }
        else{
           document.getElementById('<%= ddlService.ClientID%>').disabled = false;
           document.getElementById('<%= ddlDate.ClientID%>').disabled = false;
           _doPostBack('<%= ddlManager.ClientID%>');
        }
}
```

This line is throwing an error on runtime.

```
_doPostBack('<%= ddlManager.ClientID%>');
```

the error is :

> Javascript Runtime error : Object required.

Note : I Have a master page in the application and the DDL is in the content page.

Can Anyone help me on that.. Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must assign the client side change event of the drop down. In your code behind, have such code:

```
ddlService.Attributes["onchange"] = "validateDropDown();";
```

Don't manually overwrite the Postback stuff of ASP.NET let it handle the additional code you add.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. But can you please ellaborate it in more detail. The OnSelectedIndexChanged() in the code behind is not fired which I want to get fired when the indexManager is greater than 0. otherwise not.
Thanks. :)

Comment: Have `AutoPostBack="True"` in the tag.

Answer (score 0):

It should Help You

```
function validateDropDown() {

  var indexService = document.getElementById('<%= ddlService.ClientID>').selectedIndex;
  var indexTower = document.getElementById('<%= ddlManager.ClientID>');
      indexTower =indexTower.selectedIndex

        if (indexTower =="0") {
            document.getElementById('<%= ddlService.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('<%= ddlDate.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
            alert("Please select a Tower");
            return false;
        }
        else{
           document.getElementById('<%= ddlService.ClientID%>').disabled = false;
           document.getElementById('<%= ddlDate.ClientID%>').disabled = false;
           __doPostBack(indexTower.id,'');
        }
}
```